# How to set a responsive imageView into all sizes?

Tags: java, android, imageview

In my application I use `imageView` and height size is **180dp**.
I want set size in all devices **without Stretch** image!
**my `ImageView` codes :**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_newsImageBig"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size180"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/default_image" />
```

How can I convert this **180dp** to all size? such as : **xxxdpi**, **sw720** or ... >

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use mm instead dp if you want set size in all devices Without Stretch.

Comment: can you send to me code? because I am amateur and really need your help

Comment: just change it : android:layout_height="20mm" or some other value

Comment: This solution is not good because if you see your in 4'' mobile, you will see very large image and in 10'' tablet very small image. Instead of this try setting width and height from dimen and set dimen value in all screen configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have one of two solutions:

First Solution : make many values for your dimensions for each screen size, make sure you have all your dimensions in a resource file, make a new resource file with folder named : values-xl (for XLarge for example) and put your dimensions in this file with the same name, and android studio will automatically configure the rest for you.

Second Solution : [Second Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cpo8s.png)

As in the picture choose : create layout-xlarge variation, and it will make a new layout for XLarge screens, repeat this step for each size and make your own layout for each size (in your case, you will change dimensions only)
Good Luck.